# converting 4 digit year to 2 digit in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have file as:

```
$cat file.txt
1981080512 14 15
2019050612 17 18
2020040912 19 95
```

Here the 1st column represents dates as YYYYMMDDHH

I would like to write the dates as YYMMDDHH. So the desire output is:

```
81080512 14 15
19050612 17 18
20040912 19 95
```

My script:

```
while read -r x;do
yy=$(echo $x | awk '{print substr($0,3,2)}')
mm=$(echo $x | awk '{print substr($0,5,2)}')
dd=$(echo $x | awk '{print substr($0,7,2)}')
hh=$(echo $x | awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}')

awk '{printf "%10s%4s%4s\n",'$yy$mm$dd$hh',$2,$3}'
done < file.txt
```

It is printing

```
81080512   14  15
81080512   17  18
```

Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: Sooo you want to remove first two characters? Why all the parsing? Just `cut -c3-`?

Comment: Below you wrote *"Why my script is not printing correctly?"* : Change your last line to  `awk 'END{printf "%10s%4s%4s\n",81080512,$2,$3}' /dev/null` . When code is inside `{...code...}` (curly brackets), (without a BEGIN or END), it "wants" to process some input, it needs a record to process. There are several ways to do that with awk. Keep learning, you're doing well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't kill me for this simple answer, but what about this:

```
cut -c 3- file.txt
```

You simply cut the first two digits by showing character 3 till the end of every line (the `-c` switch indicates that you need to cut characters (not bytes, ...)).

Comment: Oh.. it was so simple, but I was making it such complicated!!!! Many thanks. Would it be possible to kindly help me in my ways of understanding. Why my script is not printing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using single GNU `AWK`'s `substr` as follows, let `file.txt` content be then

```
1981080512 14 15
2019050612 17 18
2020040912 19 95
```

then

```
awk '{$1=substr($1,3);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
81080512 14 15
19050612 17 18
20040912 19 95
```

Explanation: I used [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to get 3rd and onward characters from 1st column and assign it back to said column, then I `print` such changed line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*